# Parsing a path in an object to extract a particular folder in it

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hello I created a WPF application which displays a list of files in a datagrid from a file explorer and the user can then select the files by selecting the rows in the datagrid. On a button click the user can then fetch the path of the files (the folder in which they are stored). My default file path is  H:\Temp\Directory\Sample\Projects and I created an object

```
    var Form = new Example.Form()
                {
                    Path = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fldDlg.SelectedPath),
                    Title = string.Empty
                };

                formlist.Add(Form);
```

I want to set Projects as the root folder since it has the files that I want to display but there are also sub folders in the Projects folder which contain additional files of the same type. So I want to parse the path in the Form object so that it is built in this manner:

File1.rpt

Subfolder1\subfolder2\file2.rpt

Where Projects has to be set as the root folder.

So I want help with the following issues:

1. Setting Projects as the root folder
2. And parsing the path in the object so that it is built in the format I mentioned above
3. The path in the grid would be something like H:\Temp\Directory\Sample\Projects\File1.rpt or H:\Temp\Directory\Sample\Projects\Subfolder1\subfolder2\file2.rpt so I want to grab everything that comes after Projects.

Answer (score 0):

**1**

I would add the root path myself. *(this way I'm not sticked to 1 base path)*

But if you really want, you could use the [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples)

**2 & 3**

I would remove the root folder name from the paths:

Something like:

```
string path =     @"H:\Temp\Directory\Sample\Projects\Subfolder1\Subfolder2\file2.rpt";
string rootPath = @"H:\Temp\Directory\Sample\Projects\";

// check check, double check...
if(path.StartsWith(rootPath))
{
    subPath = path.Substring(rootPath.Length);
}
```

Gives:

```
Subfolder1\Subfolder2\file2.rpt
```

Comment: So, if I wanted to fetch a report file say file1.rpt which is directly in the Projects folder then I have to hard code that into string path as well?

Comment: I wouldn't advise hardcode strings. You should put those basepaths in a configfile. The above example is just an example, not a solution.